# Pointers assignment

Tags: c++

What is the meaning of

```
*(int *)0 = 0;
```

It does compile successfully

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will usually cause an access violation at runtime. The following is done: first 0 is cast to an `int *` and that yields a null pointer. Then a value 0 is written to that address (null address) - that causes undefined behaviour, usually an access violation.

Effectively it is this code:

```
int* address = reinterpret_cast<int*>( 0 );
*address = 0;
```

Comment: Whether it causes an access violation or not depends on the hardware and/or OS the executable is running on. The most you can say from the question is that it will cause undefined behaviour.

Comment: Yeah that's why he said "usually" :)

Comment: I said "usually" in responce to Neil's comment. He's right that undefined behaviour can be just anything.

Answer (score 4):

It has no meaning. That's an error. It's parsed as this

```
(((int)0) = 0)
```

Thus, trying to assign to an rvalue. In this case, the right side is a cast of `0` to `int` (it's an int already, anyway). The result of a cast to something not a reference is always an rvalue. And you try to assign `0` to that. What Rvalues miss is an object identity. The following would work:

```
int a;
(int&)a = 0;
```

Of course, you could equally well write it as the following

```
int a = 0;
```

**Update**: Question was badly formatted. The actual code was this

```
*(int*)0 = 0
```

Well, now it *is* an lvalue. But a fundamental invariant is broken. The Standard says

> An lvalue refers to an object or function

The lvalue you assign to is neither an object nor a function. The Standard even explicitly says that dereferencing a null-pointer (`(int*)0` creates such a null pointer) is undefined behavior. A program usually will crash on an attempt to write to such a dereferenced "object". "Usually", because the act of dereferencing is already declared undefined by C++.

---

Also, note that the above is not the same as the below:

```
int n = 0;
*(int*)n = 0;
```

While the above writes to something where certainly no object is located, this one will write to something that results from reinterpreting n to a pointer. The mapping to the pointer value is implementation defined, but most compilers will just create a pointer referring to address zero here. Some systems may keep data on that location, so this one may have more chances to stay alive - depending on your system. This one is not undefined behavior necessarily, but depends on the compiler and runtime-environment it is invoked in.

If you understand the difference between the above dereference of a null pointer (only constant expressions valued 0 converted to pointers yield null pointers!) and the below dereference of a reinterpreted zero value integer, i think you have learned something important.

Comment: Just to pile on here, yeah it'll compile, but the runtime behavior is undefined: it might actually assign 00 00 00 00 to the first bytes in the address space or it might bork your process, your mileage may vary by platform, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Its a compilation error. You cant modify a non-lvalue.

Comment: Then thats a runtime error - you are trying to dereference a pointer to the memory location 0.

Comment: Actually, it is undefined behaviour.

Comment: It's not the location 0 as some other posts also say. It's a location where no objects must be located. It *may* be location 0, but it may aswell be some other location.

Answer (score 1):

It puts a zero on address zero.  On some systems you can do this.  Most MMU-based systems will not allow this in run-time.  I once saw an embedded OS writing to address 0 when performing time(NULL).

Answer (score 0):

there is no valid lvalue in that operation so it shouldn't compile.

the left hand side of an assignment must be... err... assignable